# How to check if the date is valid and is in the correct format in oracle to insert?

Tags: sql, oracle

As you could see below the most of the dates are same but carries different format and with one of the dates as invalid. My question is how to insert this data in one go to the table as per correct format thereby discarding invalid entries without getting any errors on insert.

```
     select to_date(dob,'dd/mm/yyyy') from table
```

This would not work in most of the cases as the data might be same as below but it may be shuffled in different format. I have thousand plus of such entries and I am wondering if it would be able to work via sql query with the use of regex (i thought maybe)

[image]

Comment: So `4/9/1977` is `04-sep-1977` or `09-apr-1977`??

Comment: Cant say as its unstructured data can be considered as majority format but one thing can be if the dates are same and shuffled but corresponds to one same already inserted customer data in the target then I can check it via a subquery lookup on target to verify

Comment: `22/17/1990` - Martian locale?

Comment: Whats that.... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is regular expressions:

```
select (case when regexp_like(dob, '^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}$'
             then to_date(dob, 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
             when regexp_like(dob, '^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}$'
             then to_date(dob, 'yyyy/mm/dd') 
             when regexp_like(dob, '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$'
             then to_date(dob, 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
        end)
from t;
```

I don't really recommend this, however.  You have a *data modeling* problem.   You have stored a *date* as a string, and that is the fundamental issue.  You have no control over the inputs, so you don't know if 3/7/64 refers to March 7th or July 3rd.

You should really fix the table when the data is *input*.

Comment: Actually its the source which has this sorta random data and the data is unstructured we have source as varchar and we have it as date in target table but I have few other parameters in source like first name lastname and phone number as major keys to check if this type of date corresponds to a user or not

Comment: @gordon , it will lead to a problem when input string is `1/13/2019` . It will throw error. But good solution if OP has no such input string.

Comment: For now my assumption is I will keep the data as the format it is coming in as above regexp even i thought of same regexp to deal with such data and if there are multiple same customers data then I would use a lookup subquery on target and insert the same already inserted date

Answer (score 1):

Oracle TO_DATE() function is fairly forgiving: it doesn't care whether we use `'/'` or `'-'` as a date separator in the format mask. So I prefer to use TO_DATE() rather than regular expressions, as they express intent better and they're easier to read: I'm trying to convert strings to dates and here are the formats I'm expecting. Also, Oracle's inbuilt SQL functions are more performative than regex, which does matter in bulk operations like data warehouse ETL runs.

A straightforward solution is to use a function which applies various date format masks to the date string until one is successful. That is our winner and we return it as a date. If none of the masks fit the string we return null.

```
function cast_to_date (p_str in varchar2) return date is
  d date;
  masks sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll := sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll ('dd-mm-yyyy', 'mm-dd-yyyy', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
begin  
  for idx in 1..masks.count() loop
    begin
      d := to_date(p_str, masks(idx));
      exit;
    exception
      when others then
        d := null;
    end;
  end loop;  
  return d;
end;
```

This version applies three masks. Think about the order in which you assign masks to the array: if you think more strings represent dates as *month-day-year* than *day-month-year* and it matters whether you load 10-APR-1990 or 04-OCT-1990 then you should change the order accordingly.

Here is [a demo on db<>fiddle of this approach in action](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c7d95b6388fd1735fc43d55690aa4e87). Note that I've added a few more input rows to your sample.

---

> most of the dates are same but carries different format and with one of the dates as invalid.

Actually **three** of the eight dates are invalid, and three more could be either *month-day-year* or *day-month-year*. Which means you can only be sure that 25% of the dates in the sample are correct. Given that hit rate you ought to be suspicious of those ones too: certainly they're dates, but are they correct? And by extension, can you trust any of the data this source system is passing you? How can you be sure they are only cavalier with this one column and rigorous with all the other columns? I'll bet the *"first name lastname and phone number"* are full of dodgy values too.

Most likely you have exaggerated the numbers of bad dates in the posted sample for the purposes of the question. But if this breakdown is representative of the data you get then you ought to have a discussion about whether it's worth you time loading this data, and if you do load it, how much you should trust it in downstream processing.

Comment: Dont you think that function usage is an overhead.. Although regex is used as per Gordons answer but that is just for the condition and to_date is used thereafter if any of the condition mets. Also, as per the data Ive found that majority of dates belongs to same customer likewise Ive set a lookup query on target to set already inserted date and the customer phoneno, email etc had some dodgy values and Ive corrected those as they were minor (like phoneno length was 10 and some special characters).

Comment: Also, your point and other comments above too are also valid that which dd-mm or mm-dd format to consider when they both are valid. These as of now I could say as exception but all those which belong to the same customer Ive set those as the format in which they were inserted at first.

Comment: As a developer I use regex every day - **for development**. So I'm not against it per se. But I do think having regex in production is a concern. Because, you know, [now you have two problems](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/). In the past I have also found `regexp` functions to be least an order of magnitude slower compared to their non-regex equivalents.  However, YMMV: if you've benchmarked Gordon's solution and it's fast enough for your needs then that's fine.

Comment: I havent ran any of the answers though but I guess having a function/procedure would be too costly and running it each time for each row would be an overhead. Although, thanks for the detailed answer I could apply this logic at somepoint like a statement level etc. I am not saying that it still resolves my problem but thats source exception and I cant do much about it. +1 for the detailed answer.